# search and replace within equations

Tags: libreoffice

In a LibreOffice ODT file, I would like to replace all "d" inside equations with "g". E.g, the following equation:

```
d cdot p_d + d cdot q_d = 1
```

should change to:

```
g cdot p_g + g cdot q_g = 1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are the `$$` part of the file or did you add them thinking that this site supports MathJax/LaTeX notation?

Comment: @terdon I thought this site suppots MathJax.

Comment: No, I don't think it does. Anyway, no site supports them inside code blocks. Could you please [edit] and remove them? I don't think you'll be able to do this, by the way, `.odt` is a binary format so it can't really be parsed. Your only chance is to find a way to do it from librteoffice itself or take this opportunity to learn LaTeX ;)

Comment: @terdon I usually work with LaTeX, but here my colleague works with Word, so I have to work in a format that can be easily converted to Word..